# Display HTML text on one line

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, inline, paragraph

I am coding an MVC 5 view, and I am after some text colored green, the same as the `class="text-success"` Bootstrap class on the same line as normal text.

Here is what I have coded currently:

```
Test Text: <p class="text-success">Yes</p>
```

This however, displays the green `"Yes"` on the next line down rather than on the same line as the `"Test Text:"`.

How can I display the text on one line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That should do the trick :

```
<p>Test Text: <span class="text-success">Yes</span></p>
```

Explanation : 
`<p>` is a block element, hence displaying in its block taking the whole width (if not specified otherwise in the CSS), with a new line before and after. 
`<span>` is an inline element, taking only the width that's needed and not forcing any new line.

The difference between `inline` and `block` is a very important thing in HTML/CSS. You will also discover other values for the css `display` property, a very usefull one being `inline-block` that puts together some benefits of `block` and some others from `inline`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS to change the way `<p>` is displayed. The normal mode is `block`; changing to `inline` will prevent the line break.

```css
p.text-success {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
Test Text:
<p class="text-success">Yes</p>
```

Comment: While it's 100% true, I consider it a best practice to use existing inline tags than forcing block tags to be inline. In this case your solution implies an extra CSS rule that you can avoid just by using standard markup, which would also be slightly more semantic from where I see it (the "test text:" it tied to the green text so it's quit logic for it to be in the same paragraph...)

Answer (score 0):

The fix of this issue is simple: just use `<span>` instead of `<p>`:

```html
Test Text: <span class="text-success">Yes</span>
```

The reason behind this is, that the the tag `<p>` is defined as paragraph and causes a line break automatically (if definition was not changed through CSS).

The `<span>` tag instead is a simple text span and does not cause a line break.

Additionally you can also add `<nobr>` around it, to force to browser to not make a line break (no br stands for no  line break):

```html
<nobr>Test Text: <span class="text-success">Yes</span></nobr>
```

Comment: The `<nobr>` tag is not included in the HTML specifications and should be avoided ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nobr). Wrapping should be controlled using the CSS `white-space` property.